# Time Complexity of dependant nested loop

Tags: nested, time-complexity

I've had a look at similar questions that have been asked, and have asked my classmates for advice but I am questioning the answer.

What's the time complexity of this algorithm?

```
for (i = 1; i < n; i *= 2)
    for (j = 1; j < i; j *= 2)
        \\ c elementary operations
```

I have been told O(log(n))^2 but from what I've read and tried it looks like O(log(n)*log(log(n))). Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loops repeats itself `log_2(i)` times for each iteration of the outer loop.

Let's sum that up then

```
(1) T(n) = log_2(1) + log_2(2) + log_2(4) + log_2(8) + ... + log_2(n)
(2) T(n) = sum { log_2(2^i)    | i=0,1,..,log_2(n) }
(3) T(n) = sum { i * log_2(2)  | i=0,1,...,log_2(n) } 
(4) T(n) = 0 + 1 + ... + log_2(n)
(5) T(n) = (log_2(n) + 1)(log_2(n))/2
(6) T(n) is in O(log_2(n)^2)
```

Explanation:

- (1) -> (2) is simply summation shorthand
- (2) -> (3) is because [`log(a^b) = blog(a)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Using_simpler_operations)
- (3) -> (4) log_2(2) = 1
- (4) -> (5) [Sum of arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum)
- (5) -> (6) is giving asymptotic notation